# C++ insert class without copy assignment into deque

Tags: c++

I'm inserting a class that has copy constructor but does not have copy assignment into a `deque`, and a simple example is shown below:

```
class X {
public:
    X(const int value): value(value) {}
    const int value;
};

void insert() {
    std::deque<X> queue;
    X x(3);
    queue.insert(queue.begin(), x); // this cannot compile
    queue.emplace(queue.begin(), x); // this cannot compile
    queue.emplace_front(x); // this is OK
}
```

The compiler complains that the class X does not have a copy assignment due to the `const int value` in the definition. I understand the part that it does not have a copy assignment, but it indeed has a copy constructor, and I thought to insert into a deque, the element will be copy-constructed, hence I only need a copy constructor and not a copy assignment, where am I wrong here? And how do I deal with this kind of situation where I only have copy constructor and not copy assignment due to `const` fields?

Comment: prefer to make members `private` rather than `const`

Answer (score 2):

*"I thought to insert into a deque, the element will be copy-constructed, hence I only need a copy constructor and not a copy assignment"*. The requirements depend on which function you use :

For [`std::deque<T>::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace) :

> Type requirements
>
> -`T` (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of *MoveAssignable*, *MoveInsertable* and *EmplaceConstructible*.

`emplace` won't work with `X` because it can't be move assigned.

For [`std::deque<T>::emplace_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_front) :

> Type requirements
>
> -`T` (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of *EmplaceConstructible*.

`emplace_front` is what you were thinking of and does work with `X` since it is emplace constructible.

The reason the two functions have different requirements is that elements in a `deque` are stable under front and back insertion. When you insert an element at the front or back of the `deque` all pointers and references to its existing elements remain valid, nothing has to move.

With `emplace` that guarantee isn't provided because it can insert elements anywhere in the container. If you insert in the middle of the container, some number of elements might need to be shifted, so elements need to be assignable to allow this shift. Passing `begin()` as the iterator doesn't help, the function is implemented to accommodate the case where the iterator may not be `begin()` or `end()`.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful! I thought at least in theory, when inserting into the middle we can just change the pointers in the deque without messing up with the contents of the elements, but I guess that just depends on the implementation. Do you have any suggestion in my situation if I'm trying to put elements that do not have copy assignment (such as classes from other people's code) into containers?

Comment: @DiveIntoML The first solution should be to make the types assignable. Unassignable types are annoying to work with and generally there shouldn't be any technical reason to have them. If you absolutely can't, you can store `std::unique_ptr<X>` instead, which I think is how you think `deque` is implemented.